# VS2010 Surround Snippet - Can I duplicate the $selected$ text?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I wanted to create a surrounding snippet that uses the `$selected$` text twice - as the text and the title of an HTML link.  Here is what I have written:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <Header>
        <SnippetTypes>
            <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
        </SnippetTypes>
        <Title>My Link</Title>
        <Author>Me</Author>
        <Description>Makes a special link.</Description>
        <HelpUrl>
        </HelpUrl>
        <Shortcut>myLink</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>Link</ID>
                <ToolTip></ToolTip>
                <Default>http://www.aggienetwork.com</Default>
                <Function></Function>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="html"><![CDATA[<a style="color: #1a4e9d; text-decoration: none;" 
            href="$Link$" title="$selected$" target="_blank">$selected$</a>$end$]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

If I use this, the `$selected$` text just appears once as the text and the title property is blank.  Anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue, hopefully Microsoft will consider `$selected$` to be used as a literal in future...

[Code Element (IntelliSense Code Snippets)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171421%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#4)